# How do I get the IMDB url from IMDBPy?

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I've been using [IMDBpy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/) to collect information about movies with python. While for the most part it works great, I can't figure out how to get it to tell me the IMDB url of the movie returned from a search.
Is it even possible with IMDBpy?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Edit: On Aya's instructions, I used the get_imdbURL() method like this:

```
import imdb
movie = "some movie"
ia = imdb.IMDb()
results = ia.search_movie(movie)
mv = results[0] #First result
URL = ia.get_imdbURL(mv) #URL for first result
```

Thanks again Aya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/docs/README.package.txt)...

> The get_imdbURL(MovieOrPersonOrCharacterOrCompanyObject) method
>   returns a string with the main IMDb URL for the given Movie, Person,
>   Character or Company object; it tries to do its best to retrieve the
>   URL.